# how to know the reason of error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: vb.net

I have the following subroutine to get data from table:

```
'GetData
    Public Sub GetData(ByVal SqlStr As String, ByVal xDt As DataTable, ByVal xPar() As MySqlParameter)
        Using xCmd As New MySqlCommand() With {
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                    .CommandText = SqlStr,
                    .Connection = _ServerConnStr
                    }

            If xPar IsNot Nothing Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To xPar.Length - 1
                    xCmd.Parameters.Add(xPar(i))
                Next
            End If

            Using xDa As New MySqlDataAdapter(xCmd)
                xDa.Fill(xDt)
            End Using
            xDt.Dispose()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

and I use that sub to get data from tblfatora1:

```
Public Sub MySql_GetFhMain()
        xDtMain = New DataTable()

        Dim xPar(2) As MySqlParameter
        xPar(0) = New MySqlParameter("@Date1", MySqlDbType.Date) With {
                                    .Value = Date1}
        xPar(1) = New MySqlParameter("@Date2", MySqlDbType.Date) With {
                                    .Value = Date2}
        xPar(2) = New MySqlParameter("@FhReso", DbType.Int32) With {
                                    .Value = FhReso}

            xSqlStr = "SELECT 
                FhID, FhRef, FhCode, FhDate, FhQuan, FhPurPrice,  
                FhPurTotal, FhCarNo, FhResoDetails, FhPalletQuan, 
                FhPalletPrice, accreso.AccName AS ResoName, 
                accdriv.AccName AS DriverName, CONCAT(CategoryName,'-',ProductName) AS ProductName,

                (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(AccName) FROM tblaccounts 
                    INNER JOIN tblfatora2 ON 
                        tblfatora2.FbCus = tblaccounts.AccID 
                                where FIND_IN_SET(AccID, FbCus) AND tblfatora2.FhRef = tblfatora1.FhRef)AS TheCustomers,

                (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(PlaceName) FROM tblplaces 
                    INNER JOIN tblfatora2 ON 
                        tblfatora2.FbCusPlace = tblplaces.PlaceID 
                                where FIND_IN_SET(PlaceID, FbCusPlace) AND tblfatora2.FhRef = tblfatora1.FhRef)AS ThePlaces , 

                (FhQuan -  (SELECT IFNULL(SUM(FbQuan), 0) FROM tblfatora2 WHERE FhRef = tblfatora1.FhRef)) AS TheRemain, 
ProductPallet, PlaceName, FhDriver, FhProduct, FhReso, FhResoPlace     
                                       
                                            FROM tblfatora1
                                        INNER JOIN tblproducts ON tblproducts.ProductID = tblfatora1.FhProduct
                                        INNER JOIN tblaccounts accreso ON accreso.AccID = tblfatora1.FhReso
                                        INNER JOIN tblaccounts accdriv ON accdriv.AccID = tblfatora1.FhDriver  
                                        INNER JOIN tblcategories cat ON cat.CategoryID = tblproducts.ProductCategory 
                                        INNER JOIN tblcurrencies curr ON accdriv.AccCurrID = curr.CurrencyID
                                        INNER JOIN tblplaces plc ON plc.PlaceID = tblfatora1.FhResoPlace 
                                        WHERE (FhDate Between @Date1 And @Date2)"
       

        xClsMySql.GetData(xSqlStr, xDtMain, xPar)

    End Sub
```

but sometimes when I run it I get the following error:

[image]

although when I check the rows count I see that there are many rows so the DtMain has rows:
[image]

as I said that error sometimes happens, not always, I tried to see the reason of the error but I couldn't

Comment: What's the value of Me.DgvMain?

Comment: I can see that your problematic code runs inside a BackgroundWorder_RunWorkerCompleted. Perhaps sometimes the bkw ends when you don't have valid instances for DgvMain or xClsForm or xDtMain. Finding the problem should be easy if you hover your mouse on these variables and checks which one is Nothing. But the answers in the Duplicate above are more complete than any comment here. Please check it

Comment: @HansKeﬆing it's datagridview

Comment: I meant: not its Type, but its value. Are you very sure it's never Nothing?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing as you see there are 175 records so there are data so it's not null.

Comment: No, you are still looking at the wrong value. You try and assign those 175 records to DgvMain.DataSource. When DgvMain is Nothing, you will get this exception

Comment: @HansKeﬆing ok bro, your reply made me confused m could you please give me more explanation because I use the same thing every time and it's works!!

Comment: @HansKeﬆing could you help me please

Comment: See the comment by Steve for more info, and the linked duplicate (remember that `null` in C# is `Nothing` in vb). Sorry, I cannot help you more